# Finding values that make a system of equations inconsistent

Tags: matrices, gaussian-elimination

I'm pretty new to matrices, and only know the basics at the moment.

I was given a question that asks:

> *For the system of equations:
> $$
> \begin{split}
> x  &+ 2y &+  z &=60\\
> 2x &+ 3y &+  z &=85\\
> 3x &+ y  &+ pz &=105
> \end{split}
> $$
> find the value of $p$ such that there is an inconsistency and hence no solutions.*

I converted the system into an augmented matrix:

$$ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c} 1&2&1&60\\ 2&3&1&85\\ 3&1&p&105 \end{array} \right] $$

I've tried to reduce the matrix as much as I can, but I'm pretty sure I made a mistake at some point:

$$ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c} 1&0&-1&-10\\ 0&1&1&35\\ 0&0&(p-8)&-100 \end{array} \right] $$

How do you find the value of $p$ that makes these equations inconsistent?

And, if I did mess up the reduction, could someone please walk me through the reduction process?

Apologies if this question has been asked before, I had a good look around and didn't find anything matching this situation.

PS: I've not learnt the determinant yet.

### UPDATE

As I thought, I messed up the reduction (only slightly, though). The correct reduced form is:

$$ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c} 1&0&-1&-10\\ 0&1&1&35\\ 0&0&(p+2)&100 \end{array} \right] $$

*(Can't be reduced any further without dividing by $p$.)*

For a system to be inconsistent, it must have a row of $ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c} 0&0&0&n\end{array} \right] $, where $n\neq0$.

**Therefore, as many of you had already deduced, $p=-2$, since then $ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c} 0&0&0&100\end{array} \right] $.**

Thanks to everyone for helping!

Comment: In the last row you have $0\ 0\ (p-8)$ , which has to be a zero-row to lead to a contradiction, hence $p=8$. Correct however is $p=-2$

Comment: It would help you if you could define "a consistent linear system" first.

Comment: Have a look through the handy list of related questions at right. This type of problem comes up over and over here.

Comment: @amd What do you mean by "right"?

Comment: The right-hand side of the page, under “Related.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The determinant of the coefficient for

$$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c} 1&2&1&60\\ 2&3&1&85\\ 3&1&p&105 \end{array} \right]$$

is found to be $$1(3p-1)-2(2p-3)-7$$

Solve $$1(3p-1)-2(2p-3)-7=0$$ and you get $$p=-2$$

Comment: OP says they have not studied determinants yet.

Comment: I also think that $p=-2$ makes the system have infinite number of solutions, but that does not make it inconsistent.

Comment: @NoChance  I checked it with $p=-2$ and it was inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

[A definition for inconsistent system of linear equations](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~lee/linear/sys-eq.pdf)

> A system of linear equations with coefficient matrix A will be
>   inconsistent for certain values on the right hand side if the row
>   echelon form of A contains a row of zeros. If the row echelon form of
>   the coefficient matrix A does not contain a row of zeros, then the
>   system is always consistent, regardless of what the right hand side
>   is.

If you calculate the row echelon for the form of the coefficients accurately, you get:

$$\begin{pmatrix}3&1&p\\ \:\:0&\frac{7}{3}&\frac{3-2p}{3}\\ \:\:0&0&\frac{p+2}{7}\end{pmatrix}$$

To get a row of zeroes (all enteries in the row must be zero), we need to have:

$$\frac{p+2}{7}=0$$

This is true for $p=-2$ only.

Hence the system is not consistent for $p=-2$.

Note that the definition is very important. I am sure your textbook has definition. Maybe you should stick to that one in your material.